# grid elements not getting arranged / displayed

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Grid elements not getting arranged/displayed. My 4th article element is not displaying at all, and following all the elements are invisible. I don't understand where I am going wrong. I don't think it's important to add ratios for rows. I am trying to arrange them in simple card layout, with 3 cards in every row. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```css
.body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}

article {
  width: 22vw;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

article img {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

article h3 {
  font-size: 100%;
}

article p {
  color: grey;
}

.footer_bottom {
  height: 65vh;
  background-color: rgb(80, 69, 143);
}

.footer_container {
  width: 65%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <article>
    <img src="/1b6912acf44a49c7879a5a42f7691cac.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Admin Aug 17, 2020 2 min</div>
      <h3>The importance of the designer notebook</h3>
      <p>Create a blog post subtitle that summarizes your post in a few short, punchy sentences and entices your audience to continue reading..</p>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="/1b6912acf44a49c7879a5a42f7691cac.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Admin Aug 17, 2020 2 min</div>
      <h3>The importance of the designer notebook</h3>
      <p>Create a blog post subtitle that summarizes your post in a few short, punchy sentences and entices your audience to continue reading..</p>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="/1b6912acf44a49c7879a5a42f7691cac.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Admin Aug 17, 2020 2 min</div>
      <h3>The importance of the designer notebook</h3>
      <p>Create a blog post subtitle that summarizes your post in a few short, punchy sentences and entices your audience to continue reading..</p>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="/1b6912acf44a49c7879a5a42f7691cac.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Admin Aug 17, 2020 2 min</div>
      <h3>The importance of the designer notebook</h3>
      <p>Create a blog post subtitle that summarizes your post in a few short, punchy sentences and entices your audience to continue reading..</p>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article>
    <img src="/1b6912acf44a49c7879a5a42f7691cac.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Admin Aug 17, 2020 2 min</div>
      <h3>The importance of the designer notebook</h3>
      <p>Create a blog post subtitle that summarizes your post in a few short, punchy sentences and entices your audience to continue reading..</p>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="footer_bottom">
  <div class="footer_container">
    <div class="about">
      ABOUT FEEDs & GRIDs I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It’s easy=.
    </div>
    
    <div class="socials">
      own text and edit me. It’s easy. Just click “Edit Text” or dry and let your users know a little more about you.

      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="subscribe">
      SUBSCRIBE
      
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your footer is just overlapping the second row of the grid

Comment: @psimms i have updated it kindly check

Comment: The grid seems fine in your demo. Why are you setting your footer to 65% the height of the viewport?

Comment: I tried commenting that line @isherwood but it's still the same, I am using `justify-items` to center grid items, experimenting with that large footer with arranged items, i am a newbie in layouts

Comment: I was mistaken. The snippet editor flagged it as invalid, but clearly it's valid. Sorry.

Comment: Does it need to be responsive?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because : Not reproducible , caused  temporarly by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there was an issue with the ***Golive*** server, when I restarted the server issue seems to be resolved, any way thankyou all

Answer (score -1):

This [codepen](https://codepen.io/riza-khan/pen/zYzrgMd?editors=1100) is what you might be looking for? Your issue maybe setting a width on the `article` which ends up messing with the grid's width. They end up wrestling with each other.

When using grid, I don't usually specify a width/height of the 'cards' it is handling. I have grid do that work.

I peppered your code with some margin/padding to get a better look.

I also took out the width on the `.body` because since you aren't using (at least not yet) media queries, it is probably better (again) to let grid take care of the responsive part. So if you expand/shrink the screen, the cards will line up accordingly.